# Free 'no-host OS' virtualization and vm management for desktop

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualization, esxi, hardware-virtualization

Is there good, robust enough for every-day use, way to setup free hardware-based virtualization which would support at least Windows and Linux and also be supported by some usable, user-freindy and free vm management software? 
I know about VMWare ESXi, its free, but vm-management software for it not free. Is there something comparatively powerful?

Comment: vmware's client is free to use.

Comment: Virtualization requires a host OS, even if it's a small stub; *something* has to access the hardware.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams This is perhaps a bit splitting hair. ESXi does run an "OS", but for all intents and purposes it's not existent other than to run hypervisor software.

Comment: The vSphere client will manage your ESXi installation, get it by logging in to the built-in web server after installing ESXi.

Answer (score 0):

Citrix XenServer free version also works very well. It also has a management tool which is free.